# Using Docker, MongoDB in GitlabCI

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, gitlab-ci

In my Node.js project, I use `dotenv` package to handle configurations. My `.env` file is like this

```
NODE_ENV = development
MONGO_URL = MY_MONGO_URL
```

So in my config file to export my DB string url:

```
'use strict';

require('dotenv').config();

module.exports = process.env.MONGO_URL;
```

Later I want to integrate Gitlab CI and feel confused how to configure it to create an image and generate the environment variable of DB string url for me. Currently my `.gitlab-ci.yml` is like this:

```
image: node:6.11.0

variables:
 NODE_ENV: test

services:
 mongodb: 3.2.10

before_script:
 - npm install

cache:
 paths:
 - node_modules/

all_test:
 script:
 - npm test
```

Could you guide me how to configure and make it build this case? Thank you

Comment: The service section is wrong: the MongoDB related line should be " - mongo:3.2.10" without a space between the version and "mongo" (not "mongodb")